# Dynamic Image Replacement through call rail phone call tracking plugins in wordpress

Tags: plugins, php

I want to dynamically swap an image that contains a phone number.

I followed steps given in http://www.callrail.com/docs/web-integration/dynamic-number-insertion/images/
but images not swapped.

I installed plugin *CallRail Phone Call Tracking* and set the api key
through call rail account and paste the javascript code in the footer of
the page.

I saved the image of destination number tollfree.png in the image folder on
the webserver wiith your prescribed naming convention i.e
tollfree.8005676745.png

Then I saved the tracking numbers images with the same naming convention
i.e tollfree.8889975025.png (8889975025 is tracking no. ) in the same image
folder on the webserver.

Then I replaced the references i.e url("images/TollFreeOverlay.png")
to url("images/TollFreeOverlay.8005676745.png")

*Earlier code :*

```
<div id="main"><div id="tollfreeoverlay" ></div>
and *given the reference through css *
#tollfreeoverlay {
background: url("images/TollFreeOverlay.8005676745.png") no-repeat
scroll 0px 0px transparent;
height: 32px;
position: absolute;
right: -120px;
top: -310px;
width: 540px;
z-index: 99;
}
```

After that I moved it to an inline style inside the body 
i.e

```
<div style="background:url(images/TollFreeOverlay.8005676745.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; height: 32px; position: absolute; right: -120px; top:-310px; width: 540px; z-index: 99"></div>
```

other images also saved in the same folder with the same naming convention but still image not swapped....

When i search my website through google search image didn't swap bt in call
rail account it maintain the log that i search through google organic.
888-997-49826 minutes agoGoogle Organic
I want to swap the images as per callrail logs.So plz suggest the solution
for the same

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the trouble you experienced trying to get dynamic number insertion to work with images. Admittedly, our previous method for image substitution was confusing. We've updated our docs and simplified our procedure: http://www.callrail.com/docs/web-integration/dynamic-number-insertion/images/

Anyone that is having issues is welcome to call us directly at 888-907-4718 and we will work with you to troubleshoot the issue.

*Disclosure: I'm a CallRail co-founder*